# jQuery - run code upon iframe navigation?

Tags: jquery, iframe

I have an iframe on my page.  I want to assign a function to run when the SRC of that iframe changes (ie, someone clicks on a link inside the iframe). Is this possible? I've tried:

$("#my-iframe").change(function() { ... });

but nothing fires.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out:

[How do I fire an event when a iframe has finished loading in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30005/how-do-i-fire-an-event-when-a-iframe-has-finished-loading-in-jquery)

From that page:

http://sykari.net/stuff/iframe/

and

```
$("#iFrameId").load(function (){
    // do something once the iframe is loaded
});
```

Comment: You should add relevant info here instead of just linking. Think if this page is printed, the info for solving the question is ready at hand? if sykari.net goes down, does this answer stays relevant?:

Answer (score -1):

You could try to use a reference to the containing page in the page that's in the IFRAME. Use the page body onunload event in the page contained in the IFRAME (something like window.parent.functionname() to get at your parent frame).

**For security reasons, this is only possible if the page in the iframe is on the same domain.**