# Indication while site is loaded in IFRAME

Tags: .net

On my ASPX page I am showing other webiste in a Iframe, in fact I am posting a form to other domain and target of that form is Iframe. It takes little while by the time page is shown in Iframe. So I would like to show some indication that page is loading and take it out when page ( From other domain) is loaded in Inframe.
How do I do that? I tried onload event of the IFrmae but it doesn't work exactly the message goes away just before loading the page.
Thanks!

THis is my code. On button click event I post the following form ( Action is on the other domain)

```
<form id="frmSSO" action='<%=formAction%>' method="post" name="frmSSO" target='iframe1' onload="hideProgress()" >
    <input type="hidden" name="TARGET" value='<% = formTarget%>' />
    <input type="hidden" name="Encoding" value="B64" />
    <input type="hidden" name="SAMLResponse" value='<% = resp%>' />              
</form>
```

Comment: can you show some code? you html with iframe ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30005/how-do-i-fire-an-event-when-a-iframe-has-finished-loading-in-jquery.  For any type of content in the iframe except a PDF, it sounds like the solutions are well-documented.

Comment: alex c  The link you provide me helped and was able to find the solution. How do I mark it as a answer? Thaks you!!

Answer (score 0):

You can layer a div over top of the iframe temporarily, but there is no way to know when it is safe to hide the div.

Comment: This is what I am struggling when to hide this div, I tried onload for IFrame but it hides way in advance before the page loads in Iframe