# Close jquery modal box once iframe content is loaded

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I created a div with an id "example" and the message for the modal box inside of it. The issue I am having is that the iframe with id loaded once loaded is not closing the modal box. Is there anything I am missing here?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#example").dialog({modal: true});
});

$('#loaded').load(function() {
$("#example").dialog("close");
});
```

Comment: Where do you load iframe's content? Same domain or another? If same I might have an answer.

Comment: Same domain but it's on a different page.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
$("#loaded").ready(function (){
   $("#example").dialog("close");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it's because the wireup for the load event is happening before the HTML is ready, try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#example").dialog({modal: true});

    $('#loaded').ready(function() {
        $("#example").dialog("close");
    }); 
});
```

There's a question already about getting a pdf in an iframe to notify, they didn't think it could work: 
[How do I fire an event when a iframe has finished loading in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30005/how-do-i-fire-an-event-when-a-iframe-has-finished-loading-in-jquery)

Comment: This is a good solution and works perfectly in FF. The dialog box closes as soon as the file just hits the iframe and not when completely loaded in Chrome and IE.

Comment: Then I would suggest adding Adam's solution & changing `$('#loaded').load` to `$('#loaded').ready` ready fires once the DOM is finished loading. I'll update my answer

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses Adam, Glenn, Emre. Glenn, this last response works awesome but closes almost instantly on chrome and IE :(

Comment: I tried moving out this pdf out of the iframe and no luck. I was reading around that detecting the file fully loaded in an iframe might cause an issue.

Comment: It's a PDF loading in the iframe?  I don't think you're going to get this to work, I've added a link in the answer above to a relevant question .