# Loading Page solution - php Huge Page

Tags: php, javascript, html, performance

So, I have a huge page (1.4Mb at least) and i have to load it anyway.
I want to show a loading gif or bar BUT i cant get it because the page before stuck and when it goes to the huge page the loading gif apears just for a second.
By doing it the loading gif is worthless.
Any suggestions??

Comment: Can you load the data in the page via AJAX? You can then display an indicator very easily upon first load.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9438535/while-loading-php-script-display-animated-gif

Comment: Thank you for the tip. I'm searching for it right now.